# How to create a HitTestObject for an object that is not yet created?

Tags: actionscript-3, sprite, collision, hittest

I have a situation where I have an array of sprites that dynamically changes depending on user input. And i need to test every one of these for collision with a single object.
The only problem is i think the 'bridgeSpriteArr' values need to be non-null at compile time.
yet we have no idea how many 'bridgeSprite' there will be in the array at compile as it changes on user input.
Any ideas?

```
            bridgeSpriteArr[i] = bridgeSprite
            Main.getStage().addChild(bridgeSprite);

            Main.getStage().addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, 
            function objectCollision(e:Event):void
            {
                if ( object1.hitTestObject(object2))
                {
                    trace("hit object");
                }
                else 
                {
                    trace("miss object");
                }
            })

            Main.getStage().addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, 
            function bridgeCollision(e:Event):void
            {
                if ( object1.hitTestObject(bridgeSpriteArr[i]))
                {
                    trace("hit bridge");
                }
                else 
                {
                    trace("miss bridge");
                }
            })
```

Comment: What means `bridgeSpriteArr[i] = bridgeSprite`? `bridgeSpriteArr[i]` seems to be the element of a bridgeSpriteArr Array, but it appears outside a loop... what is `bridgeSprite` variable? Please show the relevant part of your code.

Comment: @helloflash Apparently this guy is inept in AS3 arrays, I expect the displayed code is in a loop that does not have boundaries, and he doesn't know how to determine them.

Answer (score 0):

In Actionscript 3 arrays are dynamic, so you don't need to know how many objects there will be at compile time. Instead, use `Array` class functionality to manage the arrays. Say, if you want to add an object to the array, you use `push()` method, so the line `bridgeSpriteArr[i] = bridgeSprite` should be replaced with this one:

```
bridgeSpriteArr.push(bridgeSprite);
```

There is also `length` property that you can use to check if there are items in the array, and how many are there. You can run some code against each item in the array by wrapping the code in this:

```
for (var i:int=0;i<someArray.length;i++) {
    // current item is someArray[i]
    doSomethingWith(someArray[i]); 
}
```

You should read the [manual on `Array` class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html) for further reference.